# Video/Audio framework for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, avfoundation, video-processing

I want to develop app like iMovie for iOS and Android.
For iOS I'll use native AVFoundation framework.

What is best framework to use for video/audio and image processing/editing/creation on Android?

Also it could be cross-platform framework for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is not clear about what you are asking. still as per my search and knowledge,may the link help you http://www.windriver.com.cn/mobile/pdf/08_Android_Multimedia_Framework_Overview.pdf
or http://netgna.it.ubi.pt/files/2011-GREENNETSb.pdf

Comment: this PDF is no longer available